# Field <repo_interface> in com.<package_name>.<service_class required a bean of type com.<package>.<repository>that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations

I'm new in spring-boot, and have spring-boot desktop test project with weird names, based on another example. The error given is:
`***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.test_4.test4.NonWebService required a bean of type 'com.test_4.test4.RandomTableREPO' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.test_4.test4.RandomTableREPO' in your configuration.`

And here are my classes:
`**Test4Application**`

```
package com.test_4.test4;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Test4Application implements ExecuteI {

    @Autowired
    private NonWebService service;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Test4Application.class, new String[]{"one_arg", "sec_arg"});
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        service.save(new String[] {"dummy_str", "dummy_str"});
    }
}
```

`**ExecuteI**`

```
package com.test_4.test4;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;

public interface ExecuteI extends CommandLineRunner {
    void run(String... args) throws Exception;
}
```

`**NonWebService**`

```
package com.test_4.test4;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class NonWebService {

    private final RandomTableREPO randomTableREPO;

    @Autowired
    public NonWebService(RandomTableREPO randomTableREPO) {
        this.randomTableREPO = randomTableREPO;
    }

    public void save(String... dummyArgs) {
        this.randomTableREPO.save(new RandomTableEntity());
        System.out.println("\n\n+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
    }
}
```

`**RandomTableREPO**`

```
package com.test_4.test4;

    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

    @Repository
    public interface RandomTableREPO extends JpaRepository<RandomTableEntity, Integer> {
    
    }
```

`**application.properties**`

```
spring.main.web-application-type=none
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test3
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

have also RandomTableEntity.class, but i think for the described problem is not neccesary.

I accessed several links, but I still didn't find an answer to my error.

Until i've created and tried to use RandomTableREPO, i reached the save() method in NonWebService.class, but couldn't insert an object in database... any help from the enlightened minds in spring boot?

I want to have an object saved in database, using **RandomTableREPO** interface, which extends JpaRepository

Comment: Remove the `hibernate.cfg.xml` and move those properties to an `application.properties` so that Spring Boot can create a datasource and entitymanager. Without those the automatic configuration won't kick in and you would need to manually create the the hibernate beans. Please **don't** move the `hibernate.current_session_context_class` as that will break proper tx management with spring.

Comment: so i did, but the error persists:
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.test_4.test4.NonWebService required a bean of type 'com.test_4.test4.RandomTableREPO' that could not be found.
The injection point has the following annotations:
 - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Comment: Then you are still missing something. Probably a dependency issue (like using SPring Boot but including wrong JPA stuff).

Comment: Yes, that seems to have been the problem, now it works.
Thank you for pointing me correctly.